# Decorator over a nose test case that yields

Tags: python, decorator, yield

I have the following decorator that is supposed to wrap the implementation of test case functions within a try/except block and print the log if an exception occurs.

```
def print_log(test_case):
    @wraps(test_case)
    def run_test(self):
        try:
            test_case(self)
        except:
            Test_Loop.failure_teardown(self)
            raise
   return run_test
```

This however does not seem to work on one of my test cases that calls a yield generator

Please bear with me as this is a basic example:

```
class Test_Loop:
    # ton of implementation here (e.g. initialization, etc)

    def runIt(self, name, ip, port):
        # code here

    @print_log
    def test_log_looper(self):
        for l in self.links:
            # initialize variables seen below and other stuff
            for n in names:
                # do stuff
                for i in ips:
                    # do stuff
                    for p in ports:
                        yield self.runIt, l, n, i, p
```

From debugging, when the decorator is applied, it seems that it does not even enter the first loop. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1. You never actually return the result of calling `test_case` from the wrapper. 2. You don't actually consume the generator inside the wrapper either.

Comment: Calling `test_case` from `print_log` just returns the generator; you aren't iterating over it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over your generator. Modify your decorator like this:

```
def print_log(test_case):
    @wraps(test_case)
    def run_test(self):
        try:
            for _ in test_case(self): pass
        except:
            Test_Loop.failure_teardown(self)
            raise
   return run_test
```

Comment: Thank you.  I ended up moving the for loop outside of the try block and calling `yield _` within in because I want every iteration to be wrapped, however now it won't recognize when can exception occurs..

Comment: Are you sure you need to move it outside of the try? Every iteration will be wrapped into your try statement if you keep it there.

Comment: Yes, I want every iteration of the generator to be wrapped in the try such that if any one threw an exception the log would be printed. However, I am unable to get this work accordingly.